# Django: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I see this is a common problem and understand the idea is that you cannot add many to many unless it is created first. I have seen multiple solutions for this but unsure which one to use.

**Models.py**

```
class Concert(models.Model):
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    concertid = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=False, default='didnotsaveproperly') 
    date = models.DateField(null=True) 
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(USER_MODEL, related_name="concerts", null=True) 
    song = models.ManyToManyField("Song", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.concertid) + " " + str(self.venue) + " " + str(self.date)
```

**Views.py**

```
def log_concert_and_song(request, concertdict):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Concert_save = Concert(
        concertid=concertdict['id'], 
        date=concertdict['eventDate'], 
        venue=concertdict['venue'], 
        city=concertdict['city'], 
        country=concertdict['country'], 
        user = request.user
        )
 
    Concert_save.save()
```

Should I use the User model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add to Many-to-Many relationship by using `add`
Read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships

```
def log_concert_and_song(request, concertdict):
if request.method == "POST":
    Concert_save = Concert(
    concertid=concertdict['id'], 
    date=concertdict['eventDate'], 
    venue=concertdict['venue'], 
    city=concertdict['city'], 
    country=concertdict['country'], 
    )
    Concert_save.save()

    Concert_save.user.add(request.user)
```

or as error says:

```
list_of_users = [request.user,]
Concert_save.user.set([list_of_users])
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you I'm glad I asked this question even though it seemed obvious. To me, the .add makes more sense so I ended up using that. Also for anyone seeing this problem, you need to .save() before you .add(). Otherwise this works perfrectly. Thakn you Bartosz!

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!"save" before "add" is what i mixed up.