# Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use associated_startups.set() instead

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create nested relationship but it not working as expected

**Models.py **

```
class Meetings(models.Model):
    spoc = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'SPOC'},related_name='spoc_meetings')
    mentors = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to={'groups__name':'MENTORS'},related_name='mentor_meetings')
    startups = models.ManyToManyField(Startup_info,through='MeetingStartup')
    meeting_agenda = models.TextField()
    meeting_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    meeting_link = models.URLField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    meeting_type = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)

class MeetingStartup(models.Model):
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meetings, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='associated_startups')
    startup = models.ForeignKey(Startup_info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    starting_time = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.DurationField()
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class MeetingStartupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MeetingStartup
        fields = ['meeting', 'starting_time', 'duration', 'startup']
        read_only_fields = ['meeting']
class MeetingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    startups = MeetingStartupSerializer(source='associated_startups',many=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Meetings
        fields = ['id', 'spoc', 'mentors', 'meeting_agenda', 'meeting_name', 'duration', 'meeting_link', 'meeting_type', 'startups']
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        startups_data = validated_data.pop('startups',[])
        meeting_instance = Meetings.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for startup_data in startups_data:
                # print(startup_data.pop('startup'))
                startup_instance = Startup_info.objects.get(startup_id=startup_data.pop('startup'))
                MeetingStartup.objects.create(meeting=meeting_instance, starting_time=startup_data['starting_time'],duration=startup_data['duration'],startup=startup_instance)
            
                

        return meeting_instance
```

**Views.py**

```
class MeetingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Meetings.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeetingSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    authentication_classes =[]
```

It is working well while doing GET request but on Post I m getting this error

Comment: Share the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Meetings.startups is a M2M relation and cannot be assiged directly. You need to do exactly what error message is telling you and use set or add methods.

First extract all fields from validated data that are M2M relation fields:

```
    ModelClass = self.Meta.model
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(ModelClass)

    many_to_many = {}
    for field_name, relation_info in info.relations.items():
        if relation_info.to_many and (field_name in validated_data):
            many_to_many[field_name] = validated_data.pop(field_name)
```

Create normal instance with remaining data

```
meeting_instance = Meetings.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Now create many to many relations:

```
    if many_to_many:
        for field_name, value in many_to_many.items():
            field = getattr(meeting_instance, field_name)
            field.set(value)
```

Check Model serializer create method for reference: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L972

or similar question
[Django: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72325644/django-direct-assignment-to-the-forward-side-of-a-many-to-many-set-is-prohibite)